# Is there an advantage to specifying the ContentPane of a top-level container?

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to get away from using NetBeans to create simple Swing GUIs and hence trying to get a better understanding of the whole container/layout mechanism. I'v been reading various things inline, especially https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html.

In the example code below, I can see advantages to the second form, DialogJPanel(). For just one example, the JPanel can be given a border. My understanding is that the JPanel is actually getting added to the JDialog's content pane.

In the only "formal education" I had involving Java (3 years ago), we were taught to use the 3rd form, DialogBoth().

Is there an advantage to doing so? Perhaps in some cases where the content pane needs to be manipulated in some way? If so, what are those cases?

Or is the "both" form just to make clear to a reader of the code that the JPanel is really going onto the content pane of the JDialog?

And then there's the possibility of using setContentPane(jPanelOuter). Does that have some special purpose, in a practical sense?

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;

public class DialogTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DialogContentPane dlgC = new DialogContentPane();
        display(dlgC, "ContentPane");
        DialogJPanel dlgP = new DialogJPanel();
        display(dlgP, "JPanel");
        DialogBoth dlgB = new DialogBoth();
        display(dlgB, "Both");
    }

    public static class DialogContentPane extends JDialog {

        public DialogContentPane() {
            Container contentPane = this.getContentPane();
            contentPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentPane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
            JRadioButton jRadioButton1 = new JRadioButton("My Radio Button, which does nothing");
            jRadioButton1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
            contentPane.add(jRadioButton1);
            JCheckBox jCheckBox1 = new JCheckBox("My Check Box, which does nothing either");
            jCheckBox1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
            contentPane.add(jCheckBox1);
        }
    }

    public static class DialogJPanel extends JDialog {

        public DialogJPanel() {
            JPanel jPanelOuter = new JPanel();
            jPanelOuter.setLayout(new BoxLayout(jPanelOuter, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
            JRadioButton jRadioButton1 = new JRadioButton("My Radio Button, which does nothing");
            jRadioButton1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
            jPanelOuter.add(jRadioButton1);
            JCheckBox jCheckBox1 = new JCheckBox("My Check Box, which does nothing either");
            jCheckBox1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
            jPanelOuter.add(jCheckBox1);
            this.add(jPanelOuter);
        }
    }

    public static class DialogBoth extends JDialog {

        public DialogBoth() {
            Container contentPane = this.getContentPane();
            contentPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentPane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
            JPanel jPanelOuter = new JPanel();
            jPanelOuter.setLayout(new BoxLayout(jPanelOuter, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
            JRadioButton jRadioButton1 = new JRadioButton("My Radio Button, which does nothing");
            jRadioButton1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
            jPanelOuter.add(jRadioButton1);
            JCheckBox jCheckBox1 = new JCheckBox("My Check Box, which does nothing either");
            jCheckBox1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
            jPanelOuter.add(jCheckBox1);
            contentPane.add(jPanelOuter);
        }
    }

    public static void display(JDialog dlg, String title) {
        Toolkit tk;
        Dimension screenDims;
        dlg.setTitle(title);
        tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        screenDims = tk.getScreenSize();
        dlg.setLocation((screenDims.width - dlg.getWidth()) / 2, (screenDims.height - dlg.getHeight()) / 2);
        dlg.pack();
        dlg.setModalityType(JDialog.DEFAULT_MODALITY_TYPE);
        dlg.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        dlg.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not understanding your concern. The tutorial link you provided addresses this issue and tells you which approach it tends to use. Would you not follow the tutorial suggestion when you are just learning? `Perhaps in some cases where the content pane needs to be manipulated in some way? If so, what are those cases?` - it doesn't matter which approach you use, you can always manipulate the content pane at a later time.

Comment: Personally I've only created `JPanel` objects when I need to nest layouts within layouts. But the tutorial states why they like to specifically create a `JPanel` and set it as the content pane.  Also personally I'd opt to learn JavaFX over Swing now.

Comment: @d.j.brownYes, I bought "JavaFX 9 by Example". Not a quick start guide, I'm afraid. Curious whether you think JavaFX will completely replace Swing, but that's a whole nother question I suppose.

Comment: @camickr, I would say "still learning" vs "just learning". I've written about 50 applications, though only a few for work (though a few others that are work-related if unpaid-for). At least half of those used NetBeans to create the GUI, but what little Java work I get paid to do I have to use Eclipse. (Most of it is GUI-less though.) So I was feeling like it was time to take the training wheels off.... I guess what I should have said is I find the tutorial somewhat bewildering.

Comment: There's no "immediate" advantage or disadvantaged other then the amount of code you need to type.  Since Java 1.5 (I think) calls to things like `add` and `setLayout` on top level containers are automatically routed to the `contentPane`, this is why you may still see code which either uses `getContentPane` or `setContentPane`

Comment: @Tamias *"Curious whether you think JavaFX will completely replace Swing"* - That's like asking if C# will replace Cobol. Over the past 10 years, I've seen a steady decline in thick client development jobs in almost all disciplines, replaced with full stack web developers so if you're interested in learning something commercially available, that would be for greater advantage ... just saying ;)

Comment: @Tamias as MadProgrammer said the number of actual roles that involve developing GUIs in Swing or JavaFX is small compared to web based software. You then enter a world of ever changing and different frameworks. So you're better off learning the fundamentals of the languages and dabbling in a few common frameworks for web interfaces (e.g. AngularJS, react, JSP...). No harm in learning Swing and JavaFX though. JavaFX resolves some annoyances of Swing and both are fairly similar and quick to switch between (ignoring FXML) in my opinion.

Comment: @MadProgrammer So it's mostly a legacy thing, then, and not something subtle (and potentially important) I'm missing. Thanks, it helps to know that. And thanks for the occupational outlook info too. Though I'm old enough to have taken a course in COBOL. My first programming job was in FORTRAN IV.

Comment: @d.j.brown Interesting side-note about FXML. I come from a world of XML, so that  seemed like it could be useful. My work is mostly writing stylesheets for PTC Arbortext Styler -- which I find boring. I rejoice when I get to do some programming using Arbortext Command Language which is sorta like JavaScript. And I'm really happy when I get paid to post-process some PDF output using Java and the PDFBox library. So I'm thinking more in terms of volunteer programming - educational and/or open source projects. Maybe getting into Android apps.

Comment: @MadProgrammer -  _There's no "immediate" advantage or disadvantaged other then the amount of code you need to type. Since Java 1.5 (I think) calls to things like add and setLayout on top level containers are automatically routed to the contentPane, this is why you may still see code which either uses getContentPane or setContentPane_ - Can I suggest this be an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no "immediate" advantage or disadvantaged other then the amount of code you need to type. Since Java 1.5 (I think) calls to things like `add` and `setLayout` on top level containers are automatically routed to the `contentPane`, this is why you may still see code which either uses `getContentPane` or `setContentPane`

To better understand what's happening, you need a better understanding of how a `JFrame` works...

[image: Root pane]

A `JFrame` is composite component, made up of a series of layers.  When Swing was first released, it was a requirement to use the `contentPane` directly in order to add components to it.  This is eventually fixed (?) to allow you to add/remove components to the `contentPane` via the frame directly.

Just beware, `removeAll`, isn't routed to the `contentPane` and will remove the `JRootPane`, which is messy.

Some people prefer the "old" way, as it's obvious what's been done, some (like me, are lazy) and just prefer to get stuff done